# is there any alternate way to install appium uiautomator2 driver apart from running "appium driver install uiautomator2" from CLI

Tags: appium-android, android-uiautomator, automation-testing, appium-java, mobile-app-testing

I am starting with a new project setup for mobile test automation with appium-java.  I have installed appium server in my machine but facing a problem while installing appium drivers for Android and IOS automation using commands [appium driver install uiautomator2]. I am seeing the below mentioned error
"encountered an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaVCX.jpg)
As i work in a very secure environment many things are blocked by the organizations IT team.  I assume that when i run the command to install driver it connects with external links/servers thru internet.   My IT team suggested to have the driver downloaded on my personal machine and give all the necessary files to them so that they can analyze the security threats and if everything is fine they will put it in my office machine.

Now the problem is i am aware how to install driver thru command line but not any other way. After doing a little bit of search i found out that https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver     is the place where the uiautomator driver can be downloaded and i downloaded the repo as zip file and extracted it. I am not sure how should i proceed further. Should i placed the extracted content any where or any where. Any workable suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks.